# $P^2$-irreducibility of a $3$-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

A $3$-manifold $M$ is called $P^2$-irreducible if it is irreducible and there is no $2$-sided $P^2$ contained in $M$.

Can we show $M$ is $P^2$-irreducible iff $\pi_2(M)=0$?

Notice that one direction follows directly from the Sphere theorem.

Comment: It is polite to ask your exact question.  So, if you know how to do one direction, please just ask the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

One direction is immediate by the Sphere theorem (projective plane theorem) as pointed out by the OP.

Assume $M$ satisfies $\pi_2(M)=0$. Note that this condition with the Poincare conjecture means any sphere in $M$ bounds a $3$-ball (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494524/homotopically-trivial-2-sphere-on-3-manifold)). Therefore, we conclude that $M$ is irreducible.

Suppose $M$ contains a $2$-sided $P^2$. One considers the orientation double cover $M'\overset{p}{\longrightarrow} M$ and assume $p^{-1}(P^2)=S$ which is a sphere (not $P^2$s by our assumption). As above, $S$ bounds a $3$-ball $B$ and we consider $B\overset{p}{\longrightarrow} p(B)$. It is not hard to show this is a double covering map. However, the involution on $B$ contains a fixed point by Brouwer fixed-point theorem. We obtain a contradiction.

Comment: A few comments.  1) You need to say which double cover $p$ is. 2) It seems to me that this wants to be a proof by contrapositive, not by contradiction. 3) The phrase "not hard to show" should be avoided. Either say it is an exercise or give the necessary sentence of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $P \subset M$ is a two-sided real projective plane. Let $M'$ be the orientation double cover of $M$.  Let $S$ be the two-sphere in $M'$ that double covers $P$.

> Exercise A: $P$ is non-separating in $M$ if and only if $S$ is non-separating in $M'$.

> Exercise B: If $S$ separates $M'$, then neither component of $M' - S$ is a three-ball.

We deduce, in both the separating and non-separating cases, that $\pi_2(M')$ is non-trivial; thus $\pi_2(M)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: A comment: The phrase "Exercise A/B etc." should be avoided. Either say it is not hard to say or give the necessary sentence of explanation.

Comment: @Adterram: "Exercise" says clearly to the reader "there is work to do here". "It is not hard to show" has a similar feel but, more often than not, gives an incorrect sense of the difficulty of the task.  Gowers gives evidence, here: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/princeton-companion-errata/